# wordpress get login sessions count of current user

Tags: wordpress, session, authentication

I have tried to search all over internet and also in the forums of wordpress but have not got an answer for this.

Is there any way to limit the number of login sessions a user can do.

For example, a free user can login 2 times, a gold member can login 4 times, platinum 6 and so on..

I know how to create user levels, just confused how to limit each user role to specific number of login sessions allowed.

Thanks in advance.

Patrick.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the number of simultaneous sessions for each user, or are you trying to limit the number of times that users will be able to log in before locking their account or something?

Comment: I am trying to limit the number of times a user can login, yes locking their account and asking them to upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
function my_handle_login($username, $user) {
    $login_count = intval(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'my_user_count', true));

    $login_count++;
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'my_user_count', $login_count);

    // Handle user status etc. according to $login_count
}
add_action('wp_login', 'my_handle_login', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Simon, That will do the thing I want, how will i create the blank user meta in the db?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

1. just add a field with login_count name in user table in DB.
2. When user logged in you have to check that what's login_count
   nucmber
3. If login_count is not over, add 1 to login_count

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to modify the users table. It is generally better to use [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) for storing meta data related to users. That way, just use `update_user_meta` on login and then use `get_user_meta` to get a users login count.

Comment: @Simon your way is better than my way :)

Comment: Thanks Simon, will do some research on that and try it.